# Arduino: When pressing a button return only one output

Tags: button, arduino, hardware, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm trying to make a fruit piano with my Arduino and right now I'm just using paint on paper. Still when I press the button I get multiple output of lines. How can I fix that.
Here's a video of what is happening (sorry for the quality):https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zr2mQMRO6IY

Code:

```
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>


/* DIY Piano

   - DIY Piano with Arduino. This is a very simple project.
   - ONLY needed some very cheap materials,
     e.g. pencil, A4 paper, paper clip, speaker, male-to-male jumper, breadboard and Arduino Uno board.
   - Of course the Arduino Uno board is not cheap, but it is reusable for other projects too. So it is worth to own one.

   - This project using the concept of capasitive sensor, so no switch/button is required for it.
   - Here is the link of capacitive sensor. For better understanding, please visit the page.
     http://playground.arduino.cc//Main/CapacitiveSensor?from=Main.CapSense

   - To watch the Demo of This Project:
     http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4QNT5hOHLs&list=TLlm-tAV1gEzDF4VV39VdjCSLNlfe0tTpU


   Created by:
   Oh Hai Seng || Junny Oh    07 November 2013
*/



// Import the CapacitiveSensor Library.
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>


// Name the pin as led. 
//#define speaker 11


// Set the Send Pin & Receive Pin
CapacitiveSensor   cs_2_4 = CapacitiveSensor(2,4);        // 10M resistor between pins 4 & 6, pin 6 is sensor pin, add a wire and or foil


void setup()                    
{
  cs_2_4.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);     // turn off autocalibrate on channel 1 - just as an example

  // Arduino start communicate with computer.
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()                    
{
  // Set a timer.
  long start = millis();

  // Set the sensitivity of the sensors.
  long total2 =  cs_2_4.capacitiveSensor(60);


  // When hand is touched the sensor, the speaker will produce a tone.
  // I set a threshold for it, so that the sensor won't be too sensitive.
  if (total2 > 590){ i++; Serial.println( i + " Touched!\n");}
  delay(0);                             // arbitrary delay to limit data to serial port 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arduino work with a loop, and each time it goes into the loop the whole code is executed and this is why you get multiply output on the screen.

What you need to do is to flag when the button is pressed like

```
buttonOnePressed = true;
```

and until if you get into the condition of the button pressed but the variable buttonOnePressed is true, you just do nothing, and this will avoid multiple outputs.
But make sure you set the variable to zero when the the library detects that the finger is removed, otherwise you wont be able to re-press it again.